# highcharts endOnTick option showing unspecified value on axis

Tags: highcharts

In highcharts when i have set endOnTick true on x axis in my chart, then the chart showing unspecified value in the end of x axis

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: "line",
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: 'endOnTick is true by default'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'yAxis is rounded up to next tick and stops at 250'
    },
    xAxis: {
        linear: [0,1,2],
        endOnTick: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        //endOnTick: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [23,76,45]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is related to the `maxPadding` property, which is set to `0.01` by default.

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    maxPadding: 0,
    endOnTick: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4762/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.maxPadding